# libgdx check if a stage's actor is visible

Tags: user-interface, libgdx

How to check if a stage's actor is visible to the user?

I recycle a Dialog to show messages to the user, showing it with `stage.show(dialog)`.

I already tried `dialog.isVisible()` but it returns `true` even if it isn't visible...

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by visible? Actors have a setting for visibility (returned by `isVisible()`, and it's used to determine whether to skip trying to draw it. But you would know if you had set that or not. Do you mean you want to determine if it has been scrolled out of the field of view of the camera?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I mean whether the dialog is visible to the user, i.e. usable in the foreground.

Answer (score 1):

For the Dialog you need to check `hasParent` to see if it is on Stage

Comment: thanks, what about using `myDialog.getStage()`? I found a suggestion to use this. Are both equivalent solutions?

Comment: In practice, they are equal, yes.